Mapping the Lotka-Volterra System to the Replicator System
To Show: if all $r_i$ are equal in the n-dimentional Lotka-Volterra equation then the $x_i=y_i(y_1+...+y_n)^{-1}$ satisfies the replicator equation. 
This question is equivalent to Exercise 7.5.2 of the book 'Evolutionary Games and Population Dynamics'.
I think that I should use the following know theorem. 
Note that the map which the theorem is referring to is $x_i=y_i(y_1+...+y_n)^{-1}$.
Known Theorem:
There exists a differentiable, invertible map from $\{ \boldsymbol{x} \in S_n :\boldsymbol{x_n}>0 \}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}_+$ mapping the orbits of the replicator equation
$$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=x_i((A\boldsymbol{x})_i - \boldsymbol{x}^T A \boldsymbol{x} ) $$
onto the orbits of the Lotka-Volterra equation
$$\frac{dy_i}{dt} = y_i (r_i + \sum_{j=i}^{n-1} \bar{A}_{ij} y_j)$$
where $r_i=A_{in}-A_{nn}$ and $\bar{A}_{ij}=A_{ij}-A_{nj}$.
Any tips would be really helpful
